# Build sbt project in uber jar instead of individual submodule jars

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

Been recently trying to change the way my Scala project does the assembly so that only a single jar is generated out of it instead of one per module.

```
main-project
| - inner-module-one [inner_module_one]
| - inner-module-two [inner_module_two]
```

What I've currently done is the following for the main module (the one I want its uber jar containing other modules content).

```
project
  .in(file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "main-project",
    assemblyName,
    settings
  )
  .aggregate(
    inner_module_one,
    inner_module_two
  )
```

Having the other two modules declared as follows.

```
lazy val inner_module_one = project
  .in(file("inner-module-one"))
  .settings(
    name := "inner-module-one",
    assemblyName,
    settings,
    dependencies and such (...)
  )
  .dependsOn(
    inner_module_two
  )
```

The jar file generated for the `main-project` is really, really small (no more than 5mbs in size) and only contains Scala related stuff, no project classes or such. However, other modules jars are complete and contains everything they require.

I've already tried adding the following setting to the `main-project`.

`aggregate in assembly := false`

But still no luck so far. Jars for submodules aren't generated but the `main-project` jar still doesn't contain the contents of the submodules.

Any clue where the issue could be?

**EDIT**

Tried what @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez suggested and seems to be wanting to build, however, some errors arise that were already solved within their respective modules. In a given module there are some conflicts which are solved due to some overrides, but now they are appearing again.

`[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:`

Having the `dependsOn` instead of `aggregate` affects the way dependencies are added, overridden and such?

Comment: Maybe using `dependsOn` instead of `aggregate` solves the issue?

Comment: It does work! Kinda... Dependency issues that were solved within one module are now repeated after changing to dependsOn... Should the main module include the same dependencies as its children and shading rules? @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez

Comment: And with errors I mean this kind of errors [error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:

Comment: Yeah no idea, sorry. I have never done this, just thought that may help. You probably may also want to ask in the [**gitter** channel](https://gitter.im/sbt/sbt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's divide your question into two sections, how to include the submodules into the `main-project`, and you want to know how to not package assembly the 2 submodules.

Let's start from the easier, the second. `sbt-assembly`, is a plugin for sbt. Just like any other plugin, you cann disable it using the `disablePlugins` command. Therefore, if you define:

```
lazy val inner_module_one = project.disablePlugins(AssemblyPlugin)
  .in(file("inner-module-one"))
  .settings(
    name := "inner-module-one"
)
.dependsOn(
  inner_module_two
)
```

then inner_module_one won't build a jar.

To solve the first question, we need to understand the difference between aggregate and dependsOn. For that I'll quote from [Jacek Laskowski great explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26502615/2359227):

> aggregate causes the tasks to be executed in the aggregating module and all aggregated one while dependsOn sets a CLASSPATH dependency so the libraries are visible to the aggregateing module (depending on the configuration that's compile aka default in the example).

Therefore, when you aggregate `inner_module_one`, and `inner_module_two`, you just cause then to assembly as well. In order to get those to be part of `main-project` all you need to do is declare:

```
project
  .in(file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "main-project",
    assemblyName,
    settings
  )
  .dependsOn(
    inner_module_one,
    inner_module_two
  )
```

In order to test it, I created the following structue:

```
main-project
|-inner_module_one
 |-main
  |-scala
   |One.scala
|-inner_module_two
 |-main
  |-scala
   |Two.scala
```

In order to check whether the class One was in a jar I used the command:

```
jar tfv inner-module-one/target/scala-2.12/inner-module-one-assembly-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar | grep One
```

Then, when running `sbt assembly` with the original `aggregate`, the command above provided empty results on the output jar. And when running `sbt assembly` with `dependsOn`, the command above provided one result:

```
480 Fri Oct 09 01:48:14 IDT 2020 One.class
```

If this causes conflicts, you can read about it at [sbt-assembly: deduplication found error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25144484/2359227)

Comment: That couldn't have been more clear! Thanks a lot for such a response Tomer.