# How to run tests recursively on sbt module dependencies?

Tags: testing, recursion, module, sbt

Lets say my build.sbt contains the following:

```
lazy val a = project
lazy val b = project
lazy val c = project.dependsOn(b)
lazy val d = project.dependsOn(c,a)
```

When I run `sbt test` on module d, it runs the test suite defined in that module. Is there a way to also run the test suites defined in all the dependencies?
In this example, I would like to run a test command on `d` and have it run all the tests defined in `d`, `c`, `b` and `a`.

I tried

```
lazy val a = project
lazy val b = project
lazy val c = project.dependsOn(b % "compile->compile;test->test")
lazy val d = project.dependsOn(c % "compile->compile;test->test", a % "compile->compile;test->test")
```

but it didn't make any effect

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the use of 'aggregate' following by 'dependsOn' redundant with the same modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26477388/is-the-use-of-aggregate-following-by-dependson-redundant-with-the-same-modul)

Comment: @GastónSchabas thank you, seems like it would solve the issue, but I'm afraid it will affect sbt build times (which are horrendous as it is). I have multiple modules and adding multiple implicit aggregate modules might be too much overhead

Comment: if you want an specific command that run something you want, you could consider [creating an alias command](https://www.baeldung.com/scala/sbt-aliases#1-create-a-simple-alias).